# Google map fragment is null?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to embed `Google map` in `Activity`. I integrated it a couple of times before but It's not happening right now. 
My layout file:

```
<fragment
   android:id="@+id/location_map"
   android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical" />
```

Map Class

```
@EActivity(R.layout.location_activity)
public class FIndLocationActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

@AfterExtras
void afterViewCreated() {
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.location_map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    .....
    ..... 
    }
}
```

`mapFragment` remains always `Null`. What am I doing wrong here? I also followed [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start) tutorial but still it's throwing null. I am using actual device to test the app.

Comment: **where** is it throwing null? You have no reference to the map. Secondly, yes, the map will be null until the `OnMapReadyCallback` finishes. ... Or do you mean the Fragment?

Comment: Mapframent is null.

Comment: I don't know what the `@AfterExtras` annotation is doing, but how is that XML file loaded into this Activity?

Comment: I am using Android annotations to load the layout files

Comment: Can you try and debug without annotations?

Comment: This is strage. It worked without annotaitons. Thanks for your help @cricket_007

Answer (score 0):

Check if you added all credentials for GMaps in your app, including additional egl 'uses' lines in manifest. This may be the issue why system can't create fragment.